# Why does stream_context_create successfully return data but not my Curl?

Tags: php, curl

When I first started, I thought Curl would be an excellent way of retrieving a chunk of data in the format json.  It didn't work. I tried doing some Ajax request instead, but that didn't work either.

Now, this is my Curl request:

```
$ch = curl_init("url");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Auth' => 'code',
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```

... The CURL requests RETURNS a EMPTY STRING. No errors...

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept: application/json\r\n" . "Auth: code",
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);



$url = "";

$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);

$r = @stream_get_contents($fp);

fclose($fp);

print_r($r);
```

Provides a nice array with json data. Why? Isn't this literally supposed to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Because CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER doesn't take associated arrays. You need to add the complete header.

```
$ch = curl_init("url");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Auth: code',
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: How come it never reported any errors? My error reporting is ON and is -1 and displayed.

Comment: You should use [`curl_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) if `curl_exec` returns false.

Comment: Curl doesn't really do much intelligence. It just ignored the keys and added the values as (invalid) HTTP headers i guess.

Comment: Last, since you didn't set `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR`, curl doesn't give an error if the server responds with something like a '400 Bad Request'.